# Carbon doesn't automatically convert timezone when using `diffForHumans()` on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm new to Laravel and was messing around with Carbon (this is the first time I use it or even heard about it).

I made a simple blog where it displays comment's `created_at` (a `timestamp` column) with Carbon's `diffForHuman()`. I managed to show it but instead of "x minutes ago" it shows "z hours from now" (exactly the difference between my timezone and UTC which is UTC+z) as if the comments come from the future.

Here is my code:

```
{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

Since I never change the timezone in my `config/app.php`, I assume that Carbon doesn't automatically convert `timestamp` into current timezone on `diffForHumans()`.

Do I have to explicitly set the timezone to make Carbon shows the right diff? Or is there something I did wrong?

**EDIT:**
I'm fully aware of what **apokryfos** said about time conversion (save it in UTC and convert it to client's timezone for display).

I noticed a few things. First of all, I run my app with `php artisan serve` and my DB (10.1.33-MariaDB) with XAMPP. Therefore my app's timezone is UTC (the default config) and my DB is the same as my machine (UTC+z). So I'm thinking that maybe when my app retrieved the ``` created_at``timestamp ```, my DB returned `created_at` in my machine's timezone (UTC+z) which is weird. **Why doesn't Laravel automatically convert `timestamp` into the app's timezone on retrieval if this is the case?** Is it possible that the returned `timestamp`'s timezone is treated as if it has the same timezone as the app?

Comment: What timezone is set in `config/app.php`? `UTC` or `UTC + z`?

Comment: The conventional wisdom is to have your server-side in UTC and convert timezones on the client-side since the browser does have access to the user's preferred timezone while the server doesn't.

Comment: @fubar UTC. I have to change it to my timezone so the diff is right

Comment: @apokryfos I'm aware of that, but I thought since the diff is processed server-side I don't think conversion is necessary.

Comment: From what you noted your database is a different timezone than your app settings. This might result in MySQL converting the timestamp to it's timezone and then laravel assuming that it received it in the apps timezone leading to problems. Just to note that timestamps don't actually keep the timezone.

Comment: @apokryfos this is exactly what I'm thinking when Carbon shows the right diff when I set the timezone in `app/config.php` the same as my machine. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: You could, though I will look into it a bit more. I feel like the timestamp should also provide timezone information from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because my app and my DB have a different timezone. My DB run with XAMPP and has the same timezone as my machine (UTC+z) and my app run with `php artisan serve` so and has the timezone of the default configuration (UTC).

After configuring my app into the same timezone as my machine, Carbon's `diffForHumans()` shows the correct diff.

Answer (score 2):

you can apply the time zone on the date before return in the model using accessor as the following:

```
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->timezone('your time zone goes here'); //example  Europe/Amsterdam
}
```